# Understanding singular complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm just getting started on singular homology and I've found that when we compute the singular $q$-simplices of a topological space X (which is the set of all linear mappings $\sigma: \Delta_n \to X$) we only use a few generators, but there'd be more. Let me explain myself:

Suppose we're computing the singular $q$-simplices of a line with vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$. We usually say that the singular 0-simplex is the free abelian group spanned by $\langle\sigma_1, \sigma_2\rangle$, where $\sigma_i: \Delta_0 \mapsto v_i$. However, when we compute the singular 1-simplex we say that it is the free abelian group spanned by $\langle \rho \rangle$, where $\rho: \Delta_2 \mapsto [v_1 v_2]$ (here $[v_1 v_2]$ denotes the line with edges $v_1$ and $v_2$). Wouldn't $\rho': \Delta_2 \mapsto v_1$ be another generator of the singular 1-simplex?

In general, I feel like I can choose infinitely many generators for every singular $q$-simplex.

I'm pretty sure I'm not understanding the point of the theory well enough, so please I'd really appreciate if anyone could answer me.

Comment: It sounds like you are actually talking about simplicial homology, not singular homology.  A **lot** of your terminology is mixed up though so it's hard to tell.  I would suggest that you start by not trying to think about things intuitively and instead working with the precise definitions that are in whatever reference you are learning from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confuse a lot of things. A singular $n$-simplex of $X$ is a *continuous map* $$\sigma_\alpha\colon \Delta^n \to X$$

The singular $n$-simplices of $X$ are the basis elements of the *free abelian (chain) group* $C_n(X)$, i.e. they *generate* $C_n(X)$.

A singular $0$-simplex is **not** being generated by singular $0$-simplices, but if your space $X$ admits precisely two singular $0$-simplices, then the chaingroup $C_0(X)$ is generated by these two $0$-simplices.

Also, it's certainly not true that you can somehow choose infinitely many generators for a chaingroup, say $C_1(X)$. The free abelian group $C_n(X)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module and its elements are formal sums $\sum_i n_i\sigma_i$ with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients $n_i$. These elements are called $n$-chains.

In summary, $n$-chains of $C_n(X)$ are linear combinations of basis elements the singular $n$-simplices $\sigma_\alpha$ that generate $C_n(X)$.

In order to get a better intuitive picture i would highly suggest you to look up the idea of homology, it's very well illustrated in Hatcher on p.99.

Comment: Thanks to both Eric and Zest! But could you please explain more about why can't we have infinitely many generators? There may exist infinitely many continuous $n$-simplices $\sigma: \Delta_n \to X$, isn't it true?

Comment: The cardinality of the basis of a free abelian group is called its *rank*. Similar to the dimension of a vector space, a free abelian group can indeed have infinite rank (i.e. infinitely many basis elements). But you can't choose infinitely many generators if the rank is finite.